# How can I check if redis cache table is empty?

Tags: caching, azure, redis, azure-sql-database, software-distribution

I'm using a [redis](/questions/tagged/redis) cache in an MVC application.

I want to check if the [redis](/questions/tagged/redis) cache is empty (no data) then trigger a web job which will populate the [redis](/questions/tagged/redis) cache tables data from [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) database.

How can I check for empty data in specific table in redis cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to have to disagree with @bitoiu. Do not run the keys command as routine operations. Keys is not intended to be run that way - it should be used for debug operations only.

Likewise, using INFO doesn't tell you if specific data is there, just that there is *something* there. If you have one and only one key there then sure that might seem to work - until you discover a job run went awry and stored an empty string or the wrong data. If you only intend to store a single key there might be better options for you.

If you're going almost certainly to store data from your SQL DB you will be storing a query result not a full copy of the data. This result will need a unique key. The way to test for this in Redis is to simply query the key. If the key is empty, populate it. If it is a string use get (or exists). If it is a hash then query for the specific members you need.

Another advantage of doing it this way is to avoid having a scheduled job doing it. Instead have the data-needing-code first query to from Redis. If data is there, use it, otherwise query the backend and populate the cache with the result as you also pass it to the client. Combine this with an expiration (where possible) and you get a form of liveness test included.

This way you don't need yet more services or jobs running to do what your application would normally do in the first place. If you ever have to change the backend query code you'll appreciate there being one and only one source to change. Or if someone changes one codebase but not the other.

Comment: I would not normally use `keys *` to check if redis is empty, as I never even found a use case for that. I understand you key points, but I will keep the answer as it addresses the question imo.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that by [redis](/questions/tagged/redis) cache you simply mean [redis](/questions/tagged/redis) and you're using it as a cache. [redis](/questions/tagged/redis) is an in-memory key-value data store, which can be used for more things than just caching.

> I want to check if the redis cache is empty (no data)

You mention data at points but also tables. Redis not not have tables, it has keys. For the sake of this question I'm going to give to examples, one for full "emptiness" and checking for a particular key.

**Checking if a redis instance is empty**

Using a redis-client a redis instance will be empty if you run `keys *` and get no results.

```
> keys *
(empty list or set)
```

**Checking for keys present**

If you want to check for a particular key you can simply [GET](http://redis.io/commands/GET) the value or if you're looking for a set of namespaced keys you can use `keys` again:

```
> get com.items.1
(nil)

> keys com.items.*
(empty list or set)
```

By opposition if there are values you should get the following:

```
> get com.items.1
"first item"

> keys com.items.*
1) "com.items.1"
2) "com.items.2"
```

I hope you are already using a redis client, this is how to solve the problem, you have to write the code yourself.

Comment: To the number of keys in a Redis database you can also use `DBSIZE` or review the output of the `INFO` command under the `# Keyspace` section.

Comment: good one, thanks for that. I will add to the answer tomorrow.

Comment: [Warning:](https://redis.io/commands/keys) consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance when it is executed against large databases

Answer (score -1):

you can use command `dbsize`,as below, this will return the number of keys in DB

```
redis-cli -a PASSWORD -n DB "dbsize" | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```